# Python AttributeError: module 'xxx' has no attribute 'xxx'

Tags: python, module, attributes, attributeerror

I'm new to Python and I'm working on a personal project to get more comfortable problem solving and planning things out. I'm trying to reference a variable in another module but I can't seem to get it working and it's driving me crazy. I've done some looking around at similar topics but I'm afraid I don't know enough about this stuff yet to read into the solutions and figure out how to apply them to my project. Here is the code from "phaseOne.py":

```
import difficultySelection
difficultySelection.diffSel()
print(f'   {difficultySelection.difficulty1}   ')
```

Here is the code from "difficultySelection":

```
def diffSel(mode_selected = False):
     while mode_selected == False:
          print('Select difficulty (normal/hard)')
          mode_input = input()
          if mode_input == "normal":
               mode_selected = True
               difficulty1, difficulty2, difficulty3, difficulty4 = 1,2,3,4
               return mode_selected, difficulty1, difficulty2, difficulty3, difficulty4
          elif mode_input == "hard":
               mode_selected = True
               difficulty1, difficulty2, difficulty3, difficulty4 = 2,4,6,8
               return mode_selected, difficulty1, difficulty2, difficulty3, difficulty4
          else:
               print("Input not accepted, please enter 'normal' or 'hard'")
```

With this setup I keep receiving the error "AttributeError: module 'difficultySelection' has no attribute 'difficulty1'" where "difficultySelection.difficulty1" is called.

Comment: `difficulty1` is a local variable defined inside `diffSel`, not a global variable in the module.

Comment: The function returns a tuple, the second element of which is the value you appear to want to print.

Answer (score 2):

When you do a return statement like that, you need the function caller to capture the returned data. You are not doing that. To capture the returned data (which is a tuple here), you need to modify your call to this:

```py
mode_selected, diffculty1, difficulty2, difficulty3, difficulty4, = difficultySelection.diffSel()
print(f'   {difficulty1}   ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Turns out I wasn't referencing the variable in the other module properly. I switched my references from "difficultySelection.difficulty1" to "difficultySelection.diffSel().difficulty1" and that seemed to fix things. Might create new problems but that's just another challenge to tackle!